# How to make traits to accept a parameter pack?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++17

I define some type traits like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct has_something
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <> 
struct has_something<int>
{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool has_something_v = has_something<T>::value;
```

And a function template which is `has_something_v` is a requirement for function parameter:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<has_something_v<T>>>
void some_function(const T temp)
{
}
```

When i call it with wrong type:

```cpp
struct wrong_type
{
};

void f ()
{
    some_function(wrong_type());
}
```

compiler give me a proper error message:

> `/tmp/untitled/main.cpp:23: candidate template ignored: requirement 'has_something_v<wrong_type>' was not satisfied [with T = wrong_type]`

but when i called with another template function:

```cpp
template <typename ...T, typename = std::enable_if_t<has_something_v<T...>>>
void some_function(const T... args)
{
    (some_function(args), ...);
}

void f ()
{
    some_function(1, 2, a());
}
```

compiler give me really bad and confusing error message because i don't have a parameter pack acceptable traits :

[Compiler error message](http://paste.debian.net/plain/1152444)

And if i remove `std::enable_if` from last template function, everything work fine until i send a `wrong_type` type to function which result is in crashing program.

For parameter pack, i wrote this:

```cpp
template <typename ...T>
struct has_something
{
    static bool value;

    static constexpr bool c(T... args)
    {
        value = (args && ...);
        return value;
    }
};

template <>
struct has_something<int>
{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template <typename ...T>
const bool has_something_v = has_something<T...>::value;
```

But it still fail.

How could i write a acceptable parameter pack type traits ?

Comment: `has_something<>` only accepts a single template argument, while you are passing in a whole pack.

Comment: Meaning, you need to write an intermediate traits which accept variadic arts and check for the `has_something<>`

Comment: actually the error message is not that bad, the important part is "error: wrong number of template arguments (3, should be 1)"

Comment: @LernerCpp, Can you give me a example please ?

Comment: there are only 2 errors in the message the rest is only notes that are meant to help you understand the error. The first is a consequence of the second and the second tells you what is wrong. I know it is difficult to get used to read error messages, but frankly, this one is quite clear

Comment: @idclev463035818, And how could i fix it ? i wrote [this](http://paste.debian.net/plain/1152447) but still don't work.

Comment: not sure if I understand the question, you want an error along the line of "requirement was not satisfied" ?

Comment: If you expect ONE parameter, you have to pass ONE parameter. If you want to able to do something with parameter packs, your trait must be aware of it. I can't catch what you really want to achieve? Checking ALL types, the FIRST type, ...

Comment: it is not quite clear what you want to "fix". In the first case you were lucky that your compiler gives you a super nice message, but thats just your compiler being nice, for the same code the error could be as "confusing" as in the second example

Comment: @idclev463035818, First i thought it's template fault which give me a long error message instead of ''requirement was not satisfied''. But now i know that is my fault with `has_something`. And now i what to know how to write `has_something` which a template pack and give a proper result ? (`has_something_v<int, int, int>` == `true`, `has_something_v<int, worng_type>` == `false`)

Comment: so your question is "how to write a type trait for a parameter pack that checks if the pack has only one type and that type is `int` ?" ?

Comment: @idclev463035818, Sorry for my bad asked question, yes my first and primary problem is that you say. (`int` type just a example).

Comment: i wrote an answer, but please try to clarify the question. Without the comments it isnt clear how my answer connects to the question, but I hope it does ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the trait accept a parameter pack and it's value be `true` only when the parameter pack has a single type and that type is `int` you need to change only little on your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename...T>
struct has_something : std::false_type {};

template <> 
struct has_something<int> : std::true_type {};

template <typename... T>
constexpr bool has_something_v = has_something<T...>::value;

int main() {
    std::cout << has_something_v<int>;
    std::cout << has_something_v<double>;    
    std::cout << has_something_v<int,double>;
}
```

Using `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` makes traits a bit shorter to write. I only had to make the trait accept a parameter pack, the specialization can stay the same.

Last but not least you should pick a better name. For example `is_one_int` would be much better than `something`.

PS: SFINAE can be used to create compiler errors, but often a simple `static_assert` is the better choice to get a clean message:

```
template <typename...T>
void foo(T...args) {
    static_assert( is_one_int_v<T...>, " put nice message here");
}
```

SFINAE is the tool of choice when you want to disambiguate different overloads, but if a function should simply fail without alternative then a `static_assert` is simpler.